# My code don't showing a concurrentViewers youtube api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have problem with load concurrentViewers from youtube api

My code:

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<?php
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatistics%2CliveStreamingDetails&id={ID}&key={KEY}&alt=json");
$JSON_Data = json_decode($JSON);
$views = $JSON_Data->{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}->{'liveStreamingDetails'}->{'concurrentViewers'};
echo $views;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `items` attribute.

I assume `JSON_Data` is the object you're using for store the response of the YouTube API request.

This is the equivalent in javascript:

```
JSON_Data.items[0].liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers;
```

You need to change your PHP code for take into consideration the `items` attribute of the response - I have no idea about the `{'entry'}->{'yt$statistics'}` - the data you want to read is not in that segment of the response.